# Extra Enumeration Wrappers .net

Tags: .net, linq

I have this value returned from Linq statement.

```
IEnumerable<IQueryable<IEnumerable<IList<MyDomain>>>>
```

Is there a way to strip off all the extra `IEnumerable<IQueryable<IEnumerable<` so I have just `IList<MyDomain>`?

Comment: use the extension method [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx) to concatenate all the inner sequences.

Comment: thanks that was the correct anwer.  if you answer it i will mark the question answered correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the extension method [`SelectMany`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx)

One example might be:

```
IEnumerable<IQueryable<IEnumerable<IList<MyDomain>>>> domains = GetDomains();

IList<MyDomain> concatenatedDomains = domains.SelectMany(a => 
                                          a.SelectMany(b => 
                                              b.SelectMany(
                                                  c => c.Select(d => 
                                                      d))).ToList();
// OR
IList<MyDomain> concatenatedDomains = (from a in domains
                                       from b in a
                                       from c in b
                                       from d in c
                                       select d).ToList()
```